# Schema name prefix issue in SQL query

Tags: oracle, jndi

I have WMADMIN schema. This schema is configured as connection credential in websphere datasource.

I have table in other schema/user OCS_JOBS. But the problem is my application looking for the table in WMADMIN schema.

It looks i need to prefix schemaname OCS_JOBS in SQL query to run them.

Is there any other way to run the SQL query the table which is in other user/schema without prefixing the other schema name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `SYNONYM` see it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Sorry i didn't know how to accept the answer. Now i found it and did it.